# Locating a column then searching in it (Excel vba)

Tags: vba, excel

im not sure if this is possible, but what im trying to do in excel vba:
searching for a column using the column head (e.g.:find column Name, it might be A1 in this sheet and B2 in another etc.)
then after finding the column, start searching in the rows of this column for a predetermined value.
i hope you understood what im trying to say

Comment: You should just be able to use the `.Find` function twice. Once to find the column in Row 1, then once to find the row. Will do a quick mockup now.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be great if you could share some code with us.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be adaptable enough for your needs. Just tested it with a small sample, looking for the number "3" under a column called "Test1", looping through all sheets in the workbook

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindHeader, FindInHeader As String
Dim col, rw As Long

FindHeader = "Test1"
FindInHeader = "3"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    col = ws.Rows(1).Find(FindHeader).Column
    rw = ws.Columns(col).Find(FindInHeader).Row
    MsgBox "Your data appears in " & ws.Name & " in Column " & col & " and Row " & rw

'do what you want with your data here

Next ws

End Sub
```